# SQL is removing leading zeros

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Problem: I have large tables from the data warehouse with Course Numbers stored as `nvarchar(20)`.

For the last 50 years, these course numbers have all been 8-digits, including many leading zeros for lower numbers.

But now, our cloud provider has decided to operate with 10-digit Course Numbers
A numerically equivalent value with leading zeroes is NOT recognized by the cloud provider as being equivalent.  They are using strict string logic.  But SQL Server 2008 seems to be trying to do me "favors" by treating strings of digits as if they were numbers.

If I query a table with no WHERE clauses, I get only the 8-digit (8-character) records.

The records with 10-digit (10-character) CourseNbr have disappeared.
But If I explicitly ask for records WHERE (LEN([CourseNbr]) = 10), it returns the almost 200 missing records. This just seems intollerable.  How can I do business this way?  Migrating to a new SQL Server 2017 server.  Maybe this anomaly will disappear?

```
@@VERSION = Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)
```

EDIT: I changed the storage type in my local copy of the table [CourseNbr] from `nvarchar(20)` to `varchar(10)` and now the 10-digit string/numbers appear!  And I can search for 10-character/digit records and they appear OK.  Have I answered my own question? Why should that make a difference?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example taht demonstrate the issue. A `select` statement without a `where` clause always returns all rows in the table.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not SQL Server 2017 or 2019 will solve the “problem” (it most likely won’t), you should upgrade as your current version has been completely unsupported for 6 months.

Comment: Thanks, @GMB.  I tried making a test table and it works as we would expect, it returns ALL the rows with 8-character AND 10-character CourseNbr.  My RealWorld table contains 54083 rows.  Still investigating.....

Comment: Thanks @alroc.  Yes, I agree that SWL 2008 is long out of date.  But I have no control over what version they are running.  That is one reason I am migrating all 35 databases to a new server with SQL 2017 (2019 not yet approved for use)

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. varchar(20) with value 'BIF022277' in one table ends up being varchar(10) 'BIF22277' in another after copy via simple INSERT statement. Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU17) (KB5016394) - 15.0.4249.2 (X64) is the version of SQL Server I am using. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

> 1. Return varchar without leading zeros

```
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(int, [CourseNbr])) as CourseNbrWithNoLeadingZeros
    FROM CourseNbrTable
```

> 2. Return int without leading zeros

```
    SELECT CONVERT(int, [CourseNbr]) as CourseNbrWithNoLeadingZeros
    FROM CourseNbrTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed.  I may not have been clear.  I NEED the leading zeroes in order to interface with the corporate/cloud system.  I don't want SQL to be diddling with my numbers stored as strings.  I need to keep the leading zeroes intact.